# The element 'BuildingBlocks' in namespace has invalid child element 'Predicates' in namespace

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

while uploading a modified trust_framework_extension file, i made a new claimtype and added Predicates and PredicateValidations elements but when i upload the file i get an error

***"The element 'BuildingBlocks' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid child element 'Predicates' in namespace..."***

the documentation shows that "buildingBlocks" should contain "Predicates" & "PredicateValidations" but its throwing an error.

Also is "InputValidations" no longer in the buildingblocks because i was getting an error on that as well. 
following the online documenation :: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-password-complexity-custom

**error**:: 
Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_B_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS" of tenant "abc.onmicrosoft.com".Schema validation error found at line 78 col 6 in policy "B2C_1A_B_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS" of tenant "abc.onmicrosoft.com": The element 'BuildingBlocks' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06' has invalid child element 'Predicates' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06'. List of possible elements expected: 'ClientDefinitions, ContentDefinitions, Localization' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schema

```
     <BuildingBlocks>
<ClaimsSchema>
  <ClaimType Id="newPassword">
      <InputValidationReference Id="PasswordValidation" />
    </ClaimType>
    <ClaimType Id="reenterPassword">
      <InputValidationReference Id="PasswordValidation" />
  </ClaimType>
</ClaimsSchema>
<Predicates>
          <Predicate Id="Length" Method="IsLengthRange" HelpText="The password must be between 3 and 5 characters.">
              <Parameters>
                  <Parameter Id="Minimum">3</Parameter>
                  <Parameter Id="Maximum">5</Parameter>
              </Parameters>
            </Predicate>


            <Predicate Id="Number" Method="IncludesCharacters">
                <UserHelpText>a digit</UserHelpText>
                    <Parameters>
                      <Parameter Id="CharacterSet">0-9</Parameter>
                    </Parameters>
            </Predicate>
      </Predicates>
<PredicateValidations>
    <PredicateValidation Id="PasswordValidation">
        <PredicateReferences Id="LengthGroup" MatchAtLeast="1">
          <PredicateReference Id="Length" />
        </PredicateReferences>
        <PredicateReferences Id="3of4" MatchAtLeast="1" HelpText="only Numbers allowed">

          <PredicateReference Id="Number" />
        </PredicateReferences>
    </PredicateValidation>
</PredicateValidations>
```

Comment: Hi @kbaig. Can you please include the `<BuildingBlocks />` snippet in the above question?

Comment: This is coming because XML validation is failing. Can you validate your files against the XSDs published with the starter packs? That will allow you to isolate the issue on the client and resolve it. Note that XML is order-specific so if you add elements under BuildingBlocks in an order different than that specified in XSD, then it will fail with this error.

Comment: this is the only xsd file i found "TrustFrameworkPolicy_0.3.0.0.xsd" in the directory and it has no elements named Predicates, predicate or PredicateValidations. The online documentation shows that these elements should be in buildingblocks element following this link https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks.md

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this issue when I was setting up custom policies as well. I think it has to do with the order that these children appear in `BuildingBlocks`. I followed the order listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks.

Upload worked for me afterwards with the following order:

```
<BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>...</ClaimsSchema>
    <Predicates>...</Predicates>
    <InputValidations>...</InputValidations>
    <ContentDefinitions>...</ContentDefinitions>
</BuildingBlocks>
```

Comment: I faced this issue when following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization as well. Thanks Eric for saving my day!

Comment: Had the same issue with Localization and the order is                        
    <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>...</ClaimsSchema>
    <Predicates>...</Predicates>
    <InputValidations>...</InputValidations>
    <ContentDefinitions>...</ContentDefinitions>
    <Localization> ...</Localization>
</BuildingBlocks>